# Messages hidden in the "visit every square once" puzzle

Tags: steganography, grid-deduction

I proposed my girlfriend yesterday, asking her to be my wife.
but she did not answer me.
Besides she gave me this 6 puzzles, below.
She said I will know her answer after solving the puzzles.
Inside the puzzle there is a poem she wrote for me.

The puzzles asked us to visit every squares exactly once, from start to end.
The arrows inside the squares are the directions allowed to step to another square.
Ignore blank squares.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I beg the puzzle masters here help me to decode the hidden messages.
I really want to know the poem inside them.

Hint :

> There is a sentence inside each PUZZLE.
>  The messages are inside the PUZZLE not in the picture.

Comment: I've managed to find the hidden message in puzzle 1 but no idea how to decode it.

Comment: Is the puzzle self contained or do you need external resources (besides the English language)?

Comment: @M.Herzkamp : You need something like morse code. (But not morse code)

Comment: Weird... my browser window shows the title "stenography - Messages hidden [...]" but it doesn't show in the actual puzzle title... So maybe this has to do with stenography?

Comment: @JanIvan Don't be lazy, put that in an answer instead. If anything, you deserve credit for realizing what none of the rest of us did.

Comment: @F1Krazy Boss is breathing behind my neck. So you have to wait 4 hours and I can write that down home - but big "picture" on my screen really indicating that I have nothing to do…

Comment: @JanIvan Don't worry, I know the feeling. I'd recommend deleting or editing your comment, though, so no-one steals your answer in the meantime.

Comment: What a sweet puzzle. :)

Comment: Great puzzle concept! Nice combination of themes.

Comment: signals from ladies are hard to read as usual =)

Comment: Why was my comment deleted? Btw Stego tag here is misleading, since this is just puzzle, not stego.

Comment: @JanIvan : I do not know who deleted your comment. I put Steganograpy tag here, because if I didn't say there are messages inside, Nobody will realize it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Benny and Tech already have solutions for the path part, so I'll skip that.

The hidden phrases use

> [Flag semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore), following along the path of the arrows.

Puzzle 1

> ILLMARRYYOUMERRILY (I'll marry you merrily)

Puzzle 2

> CAREFORYOULOVEFULLY (Care for you lovefully) [*sic*]

Puzzle 3

> CHEERYOUUPCHEERLY (Cheer you up cheerly) [*sic*]

Puzzle 4

> PRAYFORYOUPRAYERFULLY (Pray for you prayerfully)

Puzzle 5

> FORNEVERLEAVINGYOU (For never leaving you)

Puzzle 6

> ANDFOREVERLOVINGYOU (And forever loving you)

Comment: Ah, I was doing the semaphore using the path and getting tripped up.  Well done.

Comment: Can you also add an image showing which are the semaphores hidden in there?

Answer (score 7):

Edit: If it's just a fictional story here's the complete solution of the paths.

For the sentence in each picture, my conclusion is to look at the filename of each picture compared with the directions.

> [image: Solution for the first one]
>  [image: Solution for the 2nd one]
>  [image: Solution for the third one]
>  [image: Solution for the fourth one]
>  [image: Solution for the fifth one]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Generally speaking, when puzzles have stories to go along with them, the stories are made up, so it's okay for you to solve the other five if you can. I believe we've had puzzles involving fictional marriage proposals before.

Comment: That's right, we sure love our 'word problems'. On a side note, while you have solved the 'outer' puzzle of visiting each square, there's actually hidden messages in the puzzles, which the protagonist (and his fiancée) wants you to find.

Comment: @BennyMüller : Thank you. Can you help me to decode the sentences inside the PUZZLEs? I really want to know it.

Comment: working on it, at the moment trying to decode the filenames of the images

Comment: @BennyMüller : To help you a bit, the messages is not in the filenames. But in the solved puzzle itself, you can not decode the message without solving the puzzle first.

Answer (score 7):

Puzzle 1 (Also solved by [Benny Muller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52576/30887))

> [image]

Puzzle 2

> [image]

Puzzle 3

> [image]

Puzzle 4

> [image]

Puzzle 5

> [image]

Puzzle 6

> [image]

No idea what sentences are hidden in these.